# Create folder automatically heroku

Tags: php, heroku, web-applications, permissions, directory

I'm developing an app on heroku but I've a problem: I can't create folder automatically with php ( mkdir() method ); I believe that is a problem about permission but I'm not sure. Can you help me about this trouble? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!file_exists("BusinessDoc")) {
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."BusinessDoc/" . $this->getUser() . "/" . date("D-M-Y", time()) . "/Flyer", "0777", true);
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."BusinessDoc/" . $this->getUser() . "/" . date("D-M-Y", time()) . "/Offer", "0777", true);
    }
```

That is the snap of code which create folders